# add a mysql_query into an onclick function

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I want to make it so that new input boxes only appear if information in the previous box is correct, by checking it with a mysql_query can I adapt this code

```
function show(id){
  if(document.getElementById(id+"-link").style.display=="none") {
     document.getElementById(id+"-link").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById(id+"-input").style.display="block";
  }
}

<tr> 
  <td><input type="text" id="a1" name="em_1"></td>
  <td><a href="#null" onclick="show('b1')">and</a></td>
</tr><tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="b1-input" name="em_2" style="display:none"></td>
  <td><a href="#null" style="display:none" id="b1-link"</a></td>
</tr><tr>
```

so somewhere in here I need to add :

```
$userCheck=mysql_query(SELECT email FROM users WHERE name = "em_1")
$row=mysql_num_rows($usercheck)
if($row!==0){"show('b1')";}
```

or something to that affect, without refreshing the page. Is this possible?

Comment: with AJAX, yes but not without re-loading a page somewhere, as php runs server side, not client side.

Comment: Please **do not use** `mysql_query` in new applications.

Comment: @Stu I think you mean you need to reload the page sometimes if you _don't_ use AJAX.

Comment: To extend on tadman's comment: the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use PDO or MySQLi now.

Comment: @11684 no, I mean you could update the values on the page without reloading it if you used ajax to call another page and do the sql calls there... i.e. you have to reload a page *somewhere* (the ajax page), you can't do it without loading any new pages :)

Comment: No, you could repeat the AJAX request. The _point_ of AJAX is you don't need to reload a page anymore (at the cost of deep linking, most of the time). @Stu

Comment: hehe @11684 I think we're saying the same thing, when I say re-load I mean re run the ajax script, rather than the main script ;)

Comment: ah, with reload I mean pressing F5 @Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax:

```
function XMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            // xmlhttp.responseText -> return value from php file , so from here you can do your action
        }
    };
xmlhttp.open("POST","yourfile.php?email={value}",true); // from here send value to check in server side
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Php:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){ // which is variable from `yourfile.php?email`
    $userCheck=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE name = 'em_1'");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($usercheck);
    if ($row==0){
        echo "no";
    } else {
        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

Pass in `yourfile` URL of your server side script which checks if email exists or not and return for example yes or no => Then with help of Ajax it will be return in current document

**Note**: Don't use `mysql` extension , use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead

Comment: And if you just want to find out whether or not the query returns results, you should use `LIMIT 1`. That will give you a simple found/not found report.If you want to know the exact number of results, it's best to use a `COUNT()` query. That way you always get one row, not potentially thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, but you need to know how to use [**`ajax`**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) or [**`jquery-ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

which will help you get the data from **php** to **javascript** and then appended to **html**.

Answer (score 1):

You need AJAX to make this work without a refresh. Check out this page on W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

It's almost exactly what you want, but instead of returning a block of text, just enliven the `b1` pieces.

Comment: Regardless of your bias, there is code on W3Schools that can serve as a perfectly fine example.  Paraphrasing an answer on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource), determine for yourself if the information provided is a good reference instead of relying on a blanket statement by a 3rd party.